# Why does my repository name appear as the title in my github pages site?

Tags: github-pages

I followed the instructions at pages.github.com to create a user name repository. Then I used the github repository settings to choose a Jekyll theme.

At some point I was prompted to generate a README.md file, however no index.html was added to the repository.

[image]

If I create index.html then the problem disapears, but I am wondering why readme.md displays like this

I created the readme.md using the Jekyll modernist theme. Later I changed to the tactile theme but this did not change the title.

The first actual line of my readme.md is

```
Welcome to GitHub Pages
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Those fields are filled with information from your repository.

The name is kreed.github.io, and I am guessing your repository description is "Cognitive Load" right?

You could change them by using a custom site rather than a generated one.

Comment: Yes the repository description is "Cognitive Load"
but this field is not mentioned in my readme.md

Comment: The site is built from information in your repository. GitHubs site generator only fills the `main_content` div with your markdown file. The other content is dependant on the theme you used in the generator.

Comment: The issue occurs with 2 themes I have tried so far.

Comment: It isn't really an issue, it is intentional that the theme does this. If you want to avoid it happening, you will have to use a custom site, not a generated one.

Comment: Why would a theme do this to a readme.md and not an index.html ?

Comment: I am not sure as to why they chose to fill the heading area with those fields, but they did. You can always edit the html yourself.

Comment: Ok. 
I am studying https://help.github.com/categories/customizing-github-pages/ and  https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/  and https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135129/discussion-between-tehp-and-kirsten-g).

Answer (score 44):

Edit `_config.yml` and add *title* and *description* you would like to have instead of the default repository name.
e.g.:

```
  title: Kirsten Greed
  description: Cognitive Load
```

Comment: Thank you, brother! This should be the accepted answer IMO.